# Python 2.7.8 string slicing by letter?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, slice

I was wondering if there is a way to slice a string that's 400 letters long, by finding one unique letter to another unique letter. without having to count to that letter to find its numerical place.

```
list = [ep72lwnVSUxlGNPython7cyEKZjBqnQOfFwAB7O19FBlcSIuNXj24NfL0XyZTNL4ynjMFMY1CoOWhc5Rs9NlMCYSv4oIZruJ6ulJQjEJ7wLdt1qrEAPH5EstellatumefwuseFxELh7hHAtecwRLYeyShpFaodZBDekTiq6dIa6pSWNskixhZLab.
14 19 118 126]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Example input and output would be useful.

Comment: Given: A string s of length at most 200 letters and four integers a, b, c and d.

Return: The slice of this string from indices a through b and c through d (with space in between), inclusively.

Comment: so... `return s[a:b+1] + s[c:d+1]`? Where does the "unique letter" part come in?

Comment: Your example is not clear. Is your string something like "_tooMuchBlahBlah a b c d_"?

Comment: sorry unique letter misunderstanding ... it was unique in the since that i wasn't calling it by a number position you guys are amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the problem was worded was funny but i figured it out with your guy's help.

`data = 'ep72lwnVSUxlGNPython7cyEKZjBqnQOfFwAB7O19FBlcSIuNXj24NfL0XyZTNL4ynjMFMY1CoOWhc5Rs9NlMCYSv4oIZruJ6ulJQjEJ7wLdt1qrEAPH5EstellatumefwuseFxELh7hHAtecwRLYeyShpFaodZBDekTiq6dIa6pSWNskixhZLab'`

```
data[14:19+1] + " " + data[118:126+1]
```

output was

```
'Python stellatum'
```

Comment: What was exactly the problem you 'figured out'? Is there anything new in your answer?

Comment: It was a concatenation string slicing error between two ranges in a string in a range and adding a space between the the two ranges for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I corretly understood:

```
data = 'ep72lwnVSUxlGNPython7cyEKZjBqnQOfFwAB7O19FBlcSIuNXj24NfL0XyZTNL4ynjMFMY1CoOWhc5Rs9NlMCYSv4oIZruJ6ulJQjEJ7wLdt1qrEAPH5EstellatumefwuseFxELh7hHAtecwRLYeyShpFaodZBDekTiq6dIa6pSWNskixhZLab'
indices = [14, 19, 118, 126]
```

That will work for even if you want more that 2 strings (eg. `indices=[14, 19, 118, 126, 140, 145]`)

```
print " ".join([ data[indices[2*i]:indices[2*i+1]+1] for i in range(0,len(indices)/2)])
```

or (if you always have 4 indices):

```
print data[indices[0]:indices[1]+1] + " " + data[indices[2]:indices[3]+1]
```

Comment: ok in your data string say I wanted to split from a letter that only occurs once to another letter that only occurs once.

Comment: Still not really clear, but you can get the indices of letters that occur only once with:
`f = filter (lambda x: data.count (x) == 1, data)
indices = map (lambda x: data.find (x), f)
print indices`. You'll get [7, 9, 12, 24, 56, 88, 126, 160, 183].